# How do I embed ruby.rb file via form in a way that ruby.rb would be executed and results visible in view

Tags: ruby

let's say I want to embed this code via form in a separate ruby.rb file:

```
print "Hello, Please enter a value:"  
var = gets.to_i  
if var == 10  
  puts "Correct"  
else  
  puts "Your answer is incorrect"  
end
```

After the submit button in view user will see either results are correct or incorrect.
In a best way file ruby.rb would be embedded via form, it's more convinient, but not essential.
Could you think of how to make it work? I would be very nice to have some incentives from you.

Thank you

Comment: Are you talking about views in Rails?

Comment: Perhaps you are asking for the simplest possible way to put this on the web?

Comment: Mark Thomas this is what I been looking for. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to put a basic form up as a web site is [Sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com/). The following is a web app in a single file, using Sinatra.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  erb :guess
end

post '/' do
  @guess = params[:guess].to_i
  if @guess == 10
    @message = "Correct!"
  else
    @message = "Try again..."
  end
  erb :guess
end

__END__
@@ layout
<html>
  <body>
   <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>

@@ guess
<form action="" method="post">
  <p>Guess a number: <input type="text" name="guess"/></p>
  <p><%= @message %></p>
</form>
```

Install the sinatra gem and run the file. You'll see a message like

```
== Sinatra/1.3.3 has taken the stage on 4567
```

Then point your browser at `http://localhost:4567/` and your app is online.